# scan-build always reports No Bugs found with make but working with single file on Linux

Tags: scan-build

I am trying to use scan-build to do static analysis for my project.
When I run the scan-build with single .cpp or .c file , it reports the bugs correctly.
But when I use with cmake/make , it always says No Bugs found.

**Commands used:**
scan-build --use-cc /usr/bin/gcc --use-c++ /usr/bin/c++ --keep-cc cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/c++
scan-build -V -v -v --use-cc /usr/bin/gcc --use-c++ /usr/bin/c++ --keep-cc --force-analyze-debug-code -analyze-headers -stats --status-bugs --use-analyzer=/llvm-project/build/bin/clang-15 --analyzer-target --keep-going -enable-checker all checkers separated by comma -o reports path

**Actual Output:**
scan-build: Analysis run complete.
scan-build: Removing directory '/tmp/scan-build-' because it contains no reports.
scan-build: No bugs found.

**Expected Output:**
scan-build bugs with html reports

**Single file output:**
11: warning: Division by zero [core.DivideZero]
return 5/(x-x); // warn
~^~~~~~
1 warning generated.
scan-build: Analysis run complete.
scan-build: 1 bug found.
scan-build: Run 'scan-view /tmp/scan-build-' to examine bug reports.

I have tried all the other options mentioned in this forum, but nothing worked for me.
Tried below also,
export CCC_CC=clang
export CCC_CXX=clang++

Would be very helpful if someone provide exact options that can work and generate bugs with gcc/make.